# Duplicate value for panel data

Tags: python, panel-data

I have panel data and I would like to duplicate the value of my variable X of year=2014 for all years & for each indiv:

```
for i in df.indiv : 
df.X[df.indiv == i ]=df.X[df.indiv==i & df.year == 2014]
```

> TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [int64] array with a scalar of type [bool]

I think that another better way to do this exists but I don't know...

Comment: First try to add round brackets: df.X[df.indiv == i ]=df.X[(df.indiv==i) & (df.year == 2014)]

Comment: And you have to give some example of data, because it's not clear what the dimensions of left and right part of equation. Is it one value on the rigth side or many?

Comment: I try with : df.X[df.indiv == i ]=df.X[(df.indiv==i) & (df.year == 2014)] and no error message but nothing appened. For my data : its panel data than I hacve some individuals and some years (1 columns for individuals & 1 for years). Moreover, I have a columns X where I have data for each individuals but only for year=2014. I would like to duplicate this value for all years

Comment: Ok, now try this: df.loc[df.indiv == i,'X']=df.loc[(df.indiv==i) & (df.year == 2014),X]

Comment: If you have one X value for each individual each year it may work.

Comment: Error Message  :  IndexingError: (19       True
42      False
65      False
88      False
...
5008    False
5031    False
5054    False
Name: country_code, Length: 191, dtype: bool, 'clusters')